# Iterating a parameter pack with variadic templates in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

As part of a logging library, I would like to be able to iterate a parameter pack, writing each value to a stream.  My first attempt doesn't compile however.  The first error is "error C2144: syntax error : 'int' should be preceded by '}'".

```
#include <sstream>
#include <ostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>

template <typename ...Args>
std::ostream & Write(std::ostream & o, std::initializer_list<Args...> list) 
{
    size_t size = list.size();

    if(list.size() > 0)
    {
        for(size_t i = 0; i < (size - 1); i++)
            o << list[i] << ", ";

        o << list[i];
    }

    return o;
}

template<typename ...Args>
std::ostream & Write(std::ostream & o, Args...)
{
    return Write(o, { Args... });
}

int main(int argc, wchar_t * argv[])
{
    std::ostringstream o;

    Write(o, 1, "Hello", 2, "World", 3, 1.4857);

    // o should contain the string of characters "1, Hello, 2, World, 3, 1.4857"

    return 0;
}
```

How do I iterate each item in ... and send it to the stream?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Recursion is one option:

```
template<typename Arg>
std::ostream & Write(std::ostream & o, Arg&& arg) { 
    return o << std::forward<Arg>(arg); 
}

template<typename Arg, typename ...Args>
std::ostream & Write(std::ostream & o, Arg&& arg, Args&&... args)
{
    o << std::forward<Arg>(arg) << ", ";
    return Write(o, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/179ae66b7710d663).

Alternatively, the pack expansion trick still works, with a little tweak - you need to special-case the first item in the list:

```
template<typename Arg, typename ...Args>
std::ostream & Write(std::ostream & o, Arg&& arg, Args&&... args)
{
    o << std::forward<Arg>(arg);

    using expander = int[];
    (void) expander{ (o << ", " << std::forward<Args>(args), void(), 0)... };

    return o;
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4a5ad4de61f3aaad).

Comment: This is great, thank you for the answer. Would you mind explaining how the 2nd one (expander) works, and why you had to add the "using" keyword?

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to write a helper function to iterate over a parameter pack:

```
// Invoke each of the functions `f` in sequence
template<typename... F>
void invoke_all(F&&... f) {
    std::initializer_list<bool>{(f(), false)...};
}
```

Which in your case, can be used as:

```
template<typename... Args>
std::ostream& Write(std::ostream& os, Args&&... args) {
    auto joiner = std::experimental::ostream_joiner(os, ", ");
    invoke_all([&]() {
        *joiner++ = std::forward<Args>(args);
    }...);
    return os;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If an extra comma at the end is okay, use

```
template<typename... Args>
std::ostream& Write(std::ostream& o, Args&&... args)
{
    std::initializer_list<bool> { o << std::forward<Args>(args) << ", "... };
    return o;
}
```

Otherwise you will need recursion:

```
template <typename A>
std::ostream& Write(std::ostream& o, A&& a)
{  return o << std::forward<A>(a);  }

template <typename A, typename... Args>
std::ostream& Write(std::ostream& o, A&& a, Args&&... args)
{
    return Write(o << std::forward<A>(a) << ", ", std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Comment: While the question doesn't mention `C++14`, you could use probably use `make_sequence<sizeof...(Args)>` to handle the trailing comma as well.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a utility I like to use:

```
#define VARIADIC_DETAIL_CAT2(a, b) a ## b
#define VARIADIC_DETAIL_CAT(a, b) VARIADIC_DETAIL_CAT2(a, b)

#define VARIADIC_EXPAND(...) \
    int VARIADIC_DETAIL_CAT(libutil_expando, __COUNTER__) [] = { 0, \
      ((__VA_ARGS__), 0)... \
    } \
    /**/
```

With this, you can write:

```
template<typename... Args>
std::ostream & Write(std::ostream& o, Args&&... args)
{
    VARIADIC_EXPAND(o << std::forward<Args>(args));
}
```

Getting correct separators is trickier.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what's the benefit of the array in your solution. Couldn't you just do `((__VA_ARGS__), 0)...`?

Comment: @zneak You need a context that allows a pack expansion. A braced initializer list is one of them.

Comment: @zneak: That approach works in C++17 with fold expressions.