# Unpack arguments from variadic template

Tags: c++, templates

For one of my project, I need the use of variadic templates. Everything works well, except the unpack of the arguments.

Here's the call

```
Shader<GL_VERTEX_SHADER> vert(vertexShaderSource);
Shader<GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER> frag(fragmentShaderSource);
Program prog(vert, frag);
```

And the class that causes the problem

```
class Program
{
    public:
        template <class... Args>
        Program(Args... args) :
            program_(glCreateProgram())
        {         
            auto shaders {{args...}};

            std::for_each(shaders.begin(), shaders.end(), [this](auto s)       
            {
                std::cout << "glAttachShader\n";
                glAttachShader(program_, s.get_shader());
            });
        }
};
```

And the error

```
fatal error: cannot deduce type for variable 'shaders' with type 'auto' from nested initializer list
    auto shaders {{args...}};
```

I tried several things, like

```
auto shaders = {args...};
auto shaders = {{args...}};
auto shaders {args...};
```

But nothing works.

And here's the Shader class, just in case

```
template <GLenum type>
class Shader
{
    public:
        Shader(std::string const &source)
        {
            char const *src = source.c_str();
            shader_ = glCreateShader(type);
            glShaderSource(shader_, 1, &src, NULL);
            glCompileShader(shader_);
        }

        ~Shader()
        {
            glDeleteShader(shader_);
        }

        inline GLuint get_shader()
        {
            return shader_;
        }

    private:
        GLuint shader_;
};
```

Thanks!

Comment: Explicit is good, implicit usually not so good.

Comment: @wasthishelpful what would that even do?  what type would it determine `shaders` to be?

Comment: I'm not sure what `shaders` could be deduced to that would work in the `for_each`... because each arg is a different type

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26550065/iterating-a-parameter-pack-with-variadic-templates-in-c

Comment: I think that having the `GLenum type` be a template parameter of `Shader` just overcomplicates this whole thing... why not make `type` a simple data member? I can't see an advantage to your implementation

Comment: @qxz Type safety.

Comment: @Quentin When would you need compile-time checks on the type of a shader? In every program I've ever seen, shaders are created, immediately attached & linked into a program, and destroyed, once, when the application starts. It doesn't seem worth it for the uglyness and unelegance of the resulting code

Comment: @Bl4ckb0ne: Do you really need to be able to pass an arbitrary list of arbitrarily-typed shaders? Would it suit your needs to have a `Program(Shader<GL_VERTEX_SHADER>, Shader<GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER>)` or similar constructor(s)?

Comment: @qxz could be possible, but I prefer this way

Comment: @Bl4ckb0ne Why? Do you need to pass a list of shaders? Your code is going to be really convoluted for just creating a program from shaders; this probably isn't the best way to achieve your end goal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not really about variadic template unpacking. The problem is when declaring shaders, you need to tell its type. Is it a vector, an array, a tuple, etc.?
Since you're using variadic template for that, im guessing shaders can have different types. You would then have to use a tuple.

```
auto shaders = std::make_tuple(args...);
```

Iterating on a tuple is not as trivial as an stl container though. Here's an example that use recursion.

```
template <size_t i = 0,
          class Fun,
          class Tuple,
          size_t N = std::tuple_size<typename std::decay<Tuple>::type>::value,
          std::enable_if_t<i >= N>* = nullptr> // if i >= N
void tuple_for_each(Tuple&& t, Fun f) {} // end case

template <size_t i = 0,
          class Fun,
          class Tuple,
          size_t N = std::tuple_size<typename std::decay<Tuple>::type>::value,
          std::enable_if_t<i < N>* = nullptr> // if i < N
void tuple_for_each(Tuple&& t, Fun f) {
  f(std::get<i>(std::forward<Tuple>(t))); // current iteration
  tuple_for_each<i+1>(std::forward<Tuple>(t), std::move(f)); // call next
}
```

Overall, it's quite intuitive, we start with i = 0, call f() then use recursion to traverse every i until N. C++14 allows you to avoid recursion with std::integer_sequence, which you could search on.

If your wondering about this && nonsense, I would suggest you to read about [Universal References](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers). In short, it allows you to prevent copying arguments using references, while making it possible to handle r-values. I would suggest you to do the same for Args... in Program constructor.

Then we can use tuple_for_each to do

```
tuple_for_each(shaders, [this](auto s) {
  std::cout << "glAttachShader\n";
  glAttachShader(program_, s.get_shader());
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using `std::for_each`, you can use an array to unpack your arguments.

The trick is to use list-initialization to unpack arguments, call a lambda, and use `,` operator to drop value and use `0` instead.

```
struct Program {
    template <class... Args>
    Program(Args... args) : program_(glCreateProgram()) {  
        int unpack[] = {([this](auto& shader){
            std::cout << "glAttachShader\n";
            glAttachShader(program_, s.get_shader());
        }(args), 0)..., 0};

        // use this to silent the warning
        static_cast<void>(unpack);
    }
};
```

You can generalize this "pack foreach" by sending the lambda instead of a hardcoded one:

```
template<typename F, typename... Args>
void pack_foreach(F f, Args&&... args) {
    int unpack[] = {(f(std::forward<Args>(args)), 0)..., 0};

    static_cast<void>(unpack);
}
```

Leaving your code like that:

```
struct Program {
    template <class... Args>
    Program(Args... args) : program_(glCreateProgram()) {  
        pack_foreach([this](auto shader){
            std::cout << "glAttachShader\n";
            glAttachShader(program_, s.get_shader());
        }, args...);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way - putting the complicated stuff into its own private method:

```
class Program
{
    template<class ShaderTuple, std::size_t...Is>
    void attach_shaders(const ShaderTuple& shaders, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
    {
        using expand = int[];
        void(expand
        {
            0,
            (
             std::cout << "glAttachShader\n",
             glAttachShader(program_, std::get<Is>(shaders).get_shader()),
             0
             )...
        });

    }

public:
    template <class... Shaders>
    Program(Shaders&&... args)
    : program_(glCreateProgram())
    {
        attach_shaders(std::make_tuple(std::forward<Shaders>(args)...),
                       std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Shaders)>());
    }
};
```

Comment: Nice, but why pack/unpack into a `std::tuple` rather than have `attach_shaders` itself be variadic ?

Comment: @Quentin the tuple will be optimised away, but it allows us to effectively pass two variadic packs into the private method.

Answer (score 1):

The range based for loop fits well in this case.
Also, try to avoid extra copies using `auto` directly in your lambda.
Here a minimal, working example:

```
#include<iostream>

class Program {
public:
    template <class... Args>
    Program(Args... args) {
        for(auto &&arg: { args... }) {
            std::cout << "do whatever you want" << std::endl;
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    Program p{42, 0, 1};
}
```

Here is your code reviewed:

```
class Program {
public:
    template <class... Args>
    Program(Args... args) : program_(glCreateProgram()) {
        for(auto &&s: { args... }) {
            std::cout << "glAttachShader" << std::endl;
            glAttachShader(program_, s.get_shader());
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Clang 3.8.1 doesnt really like it `fatal error: cannot deduce actual type for variable '__range' with type 'auto &&' from initializer list`

Comment: @Bl4ckb0ne Actually [it likes it](https://godbolt.org/g/E4228C). Did you use at least `-std=c++11`?